# Quit my job due to unethical/ilegal practices

Tags: ethics, resignation, quitting, unprofessional-behavior, notice-period

I am currently working in a recruitment company in the UK that it is entirely based on a illegal scheme where people within the company pretend to be some of the candidates, they create fake CVs and things like that.

The thing is that if I want to quit my job I have to give 3 months notice but I have heard that I can claim working under unethical/Illegal conditions and by law (I am not sure about this bit) the manager have to solve the issue in 2 weeks and if he doesn't, I can leave before the three months notice and I will still get paid for those three months.

Does anyone have some information about this?

Comment: Legal questions and questions about corporate policy should not be posted on workplace stack exchange.

Comment: If they are willing to break laws now, what makes you think they would agree to pay the 3 months to you, even if they are obligated to do that? Are you willing to take this to court and prove their illegal doing, if necessary?

Answer (score 4):

I'd implore you to have a careful read of your contract and make sure it mentions the Public Interest Disclosure Act 1998. [Read here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Interest_Disclosure_Act_1998)

You do not need to leave your job to remedy the illegal activity. You can either rat on the employees that are doing this to your employers, or if it is a company-wide policy, you can inform the police about the practice.

This will almost certainly make your job a bit uncomfortable, but they can't do anything to you, and if they do, you can take them to tribunal.